# Retrieving the 2 values in MS access data photos

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Hello I just want a little help about my VB.net program..I just want to display to my 2 picture box the data from my database (MS access)..There's no error in my code.  In terms of Output my 2 picture box where Picturebox1 is displayed but the picturebox6 can't displayed.  How can I display the two picture at the same time?

Look at the Output below

Here's what I've already done :

```
Private Sub ownerec_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Para sa Pag Connect sa Database
    Try
        With OleCn
            If .State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                .ConnectionString = StrConnection()
                .Open()
                With OleDa
                    .SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand()
                    .SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [vehicles]"
                    .SelectCommand.Connection = OleCn

                    Dim Ole As New OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDa) 'For Delete...

                    .DeleteCommand = New OleDbCommand()
                    .DeleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [vehicles] WHERE (ID = @ID)"
                    .DeleteCommand.Connection = OleCn
                    .DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, "ID")

                    DtaSet.Clear()
                    .Fill(DtaSet, "vehicles")

                    Label1.Text = DtaSet.Tables("vehicles").Rows.Count


                    Call DataConnection(Me.DataGridView1)

                    Me.PictureBox6.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Image", DtaSet, "vehicles.Owner_pic", True))
                    Me.PictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Image", DtaSet, "vehicles.Vehic_pic", True))



                End With
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error...")
    Finally
        OleCn.Close()
    End Try
    Me.KeyPreview = True

    Me.DataGridView1.Focus()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally I already added data's in my ms access database including a long binary data which is the image added using my running form....Vehic_pic and Owner_pic values